# Execute a fact if the variable of previous fact has no result

Tags: prolog

I am implementing a Prolog program for trigonometric identities. This is a part of the program.

```
simplify_exp(Term1+Term2,X,Y) :- isolaxt(Term1+Term2,Y),
        (nonvar(Y)-> simplify_exp(Term1,X,Y), simplify_exp(Term2,X,Y)).

isolaxt(sin(U)^2+cos(U)^2,1).
```

I want to execute the if statement only if `Y` has no value (when `isolaxt` is failed only). Even though I included `nonvar(Y)` it didn't work. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get if that's the only `isolaxt` clause you have or if you included it to exemplify.

Anyway, if `isolaxt` fails then `simplify_exp` will fail without reaching `nonvar(Y)`.
Is that the behavior you expect? Perhaps you meant to use `;` like so:

```
simplify_exp(Term1+Term2,X,Y) :- 
isolaxt(Term1+Term2,Y); (simplify_exp(Term1,X,Y), simplify_exp(Term2,X,Y)).
```

This means either `isolaxt` will succeed *or* you're going to proceed with the calls to `simplify_exp`.

Also, note that `nonvar(Y)` will *fail* when `isolaxt` succeeds, so maybe you expected to use `var(Y)` instead.

Comment: I included formulas in isolaxt clause. I used ';', but I don't need to execute simplify_exp if isolaxt is true. If I use ';' simplify_exp is also executed although isolaxt is true.

Comment: No, it isn't. In prolog, when you express a logical disjunction ("or") using `;` in the form `p(A) ; p(B)`, then `p(B)` will not execute when `p(a)` succeeds. 

In fact,  `q(A,B):- p(A) ; p(B)` is exactly the same as having two separate clauses `q(A,_):- p(A).` and `q(_,B):- p(B).`.